# Setting margin for label next to checkbox

Tags: html, css

I want to set a margin for text, next to my checkbox. In my HTML it looks like it's one line, but on my site, because of font, it takes two (and that's very ok with me).

No matter what I do: if I do it with padding, margin, or border, every time, only the first row of my text goes a little bit to right, but the second line is stying exactly next to my checkbox. Could you help me?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afj206cr/)

```css
.contact input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  outline: 1px solid #24ba9f;
  float: left;
}
.contact label {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Put `.contact input { margin-right: 20px; }` and let's done

Answer (score 2):

here you go

```css
.contact input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  outline: 1px solid #24ba9f;
  float: left;
}

.contact label {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.contact span {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span>Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this works

```
<div class="contact">
   <input type="checkbox" id="test" checked/>
  <label for="test">Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</label>
</div>

.contact input{
  width:50px;
}
.contact label{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sr947nh5/)**

You have to place `checkbox` outside label and you can give `margin-right` for checkbox.

**Update**:  **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sr947nh5/2/)**

You can even place the `checkbox` inside the label as here `margin right` has been specified with same css only `HTML structure` changed

```
<div class="contact">
             <label><input type="checkbox" checked> 
                Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
                Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
                Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
                Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum
              </label>
            </div>
```

So output will be like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks <3 sometimes I am so tired, that I'm not seeing the little, obvious things.

Comment: But remember: if you put the check-box outside the label you need to use the `for` attribute to associate the label and the input.

Comment: Are better solutions than modify the html structure. Not necessary put out of the label the input. And it's better if you share a working example, instead of a screenshot (that can be removed in the future)